# Search a text from div(page) will crash second time using query

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am implementing the search functionality after search word is highlighted .Actually I also implement next and previous functionality .Actually when i run it search the word correctly and user go next and previous (finely).
But when user search second time it highlight the first word also.
Here i am implementing this functionality.
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/wjLmx/2/

If you check error :

First search : sd then go next .
again search df.
You find it highlight the first word also.

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
        //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
        var selector = selector || "#realTimeContents"; //use body as selector if none provided
        var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
        var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
            $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted'); //Remove old search highlights
            $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');
            $('.next_h').on('click', i = 1, function () {

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');

                i = i + 1;
                k = i - 2;

            });
            $('.previous_h').on('click', k = 1, function () {

                if (matches.length > k && k > 0) {
                    $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                    $('.match').eq(k).addClass('highlighted');
                    k = k - 1;
                    i = k + 2;

                }
            });

            if ($('.highlighted:first').length) { //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.searchButtonClickText_h', function (event) {

    $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
    if (!searchAndHighlight($('.textSearchvalue_h').val())) {
        alert("No results found");
    }
});
```

Comment: If I may suggest, look through text nodes (nodeType == 3) and not just every node. When you match a target, split the text node into the text before, an element containing the highlighted text, and the text after, when you unselect merge again.

Comment: Sir can you do on fiddle .Or change my fiddle .so that i can understand well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for your next/previous function:

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLv9d/)**

```
$('.next_h').off('click').on('click', i = 1, function () {
    if (i==  matches.length - 1){i = 1 }
    else{i++;};
    move(i);
});

$('.previous_h').off('click').on('click', k = 0, function () {
    if (i==1){i = matches.length - 1 }
    else{i--;};
    move(i);
    });
function move(nr){
        $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
        $('.match').eq(nr).addClass('highlighted');
        $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.match').eq(nr).offset().top
        }, 300);
        console.log($('.match').eq(nr).offset().top + ' offset');
};
```

Comment: Hi 90 % your solution is correct..!! But if you search a text "naveen" press search it search first it ok.Then press next it is not search second text , it search third  existing element

Comment: Hi sir your scrolling is working well in your demo ..can you add scrolling in this example because in this every thing is working fine only problem of scrolling it the text below or above it then it scroll here is correct solution http://jsfiddle.net/wjLmx/18/

Comment: Your previous button is not  working .This fiddle is working fine only scrolling issue.http://jsfiddle.net/wjLmx/18/ add scroll here

Comment: i check on fiddle only chrome.

Comment: next and search is working correctly previous button break check "naveen" then search next previous click again -2

Comment: Thanks working fine .can you help in these question also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648366/sql-query-not-working-in-slite-phonegap-count-the-number-of-element-in-table

Comment: secondly this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649204/how-to-get-email-notification-in-email-composer-plugin-in-phonegap

Comment: There is problem in your solution..If user search for "&" ,Then? &amp append when user press search button

Comment: Secondly When you search a text example "N" it convert all small "n" into capital "N"

Comment: If you want the search to be case sensitive, remove the "i" in the regex "ig". Like: `var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "g");`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wjLmx/25/

Comment: But what about first issue if i add "&" or some special character it append that..

Comment: you can't understand my first issue also..it not work searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "g")..because if you search "N" .it is showing there is no match .but there lot of "n".i mean to say it search all "n".but it not replace small n to capital N

Comment: @Rohit, check here (http://jsfiddle.net/4BAau/) about the "&" problem. The other problem is a regex/replace issue. You need to ask a question about it, it's not my strong side.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove previous matches : <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjLmx/7/)</kbd>

```
        //Remove the previous matches
        $span = $('#realTimeContents span');
        $span.replaceWith($span.html());
```

**UPDATE**
http://jsfiddle.net/wjLmx/16/

Comment: There is two Problem in that solution ..But it's a awesome answer

Comment: @Rohit, the console errors are a bug in jQuery mobile. Check https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5490 and change to jQuery 2 with mobile 1.3.1.

Comment: Firstly I take example in my div there are two text "naveen".please enter this click search it search 1 text upto this fine.Then press next it is not showing second text .Then press "naveen" it is showing third .And press next fourth one which is at the end so scroll property cease(stop scrolling)

Comment: I am not talking about bugs .I am just checking functionality.it is not highlighting the second text and stop scrolling if text is below the page

Comment: Second issue is that as we know familiar search functionality that if user search text "a" if there is 2 matches it moving around.mean if user press next -2 and the word is last match .then again it goes to first then start iteration

Comment: I think there is problem in my logic .!!there is problem in previous button also.:(

Comment: @Rohit, does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/jGT5a/ ? I just added and empty call to the function on search click. To reset values.

Comment: yes..reset it ok .But there different issues as i commented above .Please read properly

Comment: please check as a user .and what should be he functionality .I thing it is not working fine..

Comment: can you please tell me the functionality to search text..!!

Comment: Hi thanks your answer is awesome ..!! But only only one problem it is not scrolling if the text is below or above the page..http://jsfiddle.net/wjLmx/18/

Comment: yes your answer is correct ..Thanks Only one problem if the text is above or below page it is not scrolling ,,