# sql Query Not Working in slite + phonegap (count the Number of element in table of given name)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, cordova

i counting the number of element exit in that table but it is not working?
I try like that

```
alert($('.caseName_h').val());
```

I am getting alert of this val ;
After that code is break

```
var tt  =tx.executeSql('SELECT 1 FROM CaseTable WHERE CaseName ='+"'+ $('.caseName_h').val()+'");
```

I also call like this
 var tt  =tx.executeSql('SELECT 1 FROM CaseTable WHERE CaseName ='+ $(".caseName_h").val());
  alert(tt)

**Undefined come**

Comment: No undefine  comimg ..!! i need to do dublicate functionality

Comment: I don't know sqlite but you are trying to make a sql select from jQuery/client side? Sounds like you need ajax...

Comment: ok i will try my own..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
            var caseName_h = $('.caseName_h').val();
            $yoursql = 'SELECT 1 FROM CaseTable WHERE CaseName = "'+caseName_h+'"';
            tx.executeSql($yoursql, [], function (tx, results) {
                if ( results.rows.length == 0 ) {
                    console.log(results.rows);
                }
            });
});
```