# How to get email notification in email composer plugin in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on email attachment using email composer plugin in phonegap.
I imsert `.h` `.m` file and `.js` file.
But i don't get any notification of email sent or fail.
Link here: https://github.com/GalCohen/EmailComposer-phonegap-plugin.

How to get these status
0: email composition cancelled (cancel button pressed and draft not saved)
1: email saved (cancel button pressed but draft saved)
2: email sent
3: send failed
4: email not sent (something wrong happened)

```
 window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function(result){console.log(result);},"Look at this photo","Take a look at <b>this<b/>:",["example@email.com", "johndoe@email.org"],[],[],true,[PATH,Email_PATH]);
```

Answer (score -1):

window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function(result){console.log(result);},"Look at this photo","Take a look at this:",["example@email.com", "johndoe@email.org"],[],[],true,[PATH,Email_PATH]);

```
**function(result){console.log(result);**
```

Here is the status of my email .